# Understanding ExampleMetrics.java in sonar-custom-plugin-example

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube, metrics

I do need some help how exactly this class is working. I've seen this code in a similar manner in several plugins already, but even when I copy the exact code into my IDE I get errors.

First the code in question @ [github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/measures/ExampleMetrics.java) :

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.List;

import org.sonar.api.measures.CoreMetrics;
import org.sonar.api.measures.Metric;
import org.sonar.api.measures.Metrics;

public class ExampleMetrics implements Metrics {

  public static final Metric<Integer> FILENAME_SIZE = new Metric.Builder("filename_size", "Filename Size", Metric.ValueType.INT)
    .setDescription("Number of characters of file names")
    .setDirection(Metric.DIRECTION_BETTER)
    .setQualitative(false)
    .setDomain(CoreMetrics.DOMAIN_GENERAL)
    .create();

  public static final Metric<Integer> FILENAME_SIZE_RATING = new Metric.Builder("filename_size_rating", "Filename Size Rating", Metric.ValueType.RATING)
    .setDescription("Rating based on size of file names")
    .setDirection(Metric.DIRECTION_BETTER)
    .setQualitative(true)
    .setDomain(CoreMetrics.DOMAIN_GENERAL)
    .create();

  @Override
  public List<Metric> getMetrics() {
    return asList(FILENAME_SIZE, FILENAME_SIZE_RATING);
  }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Metric<Integer>> to List<Metric>
```

and if I do the following:

```
public List<Metric<Integer>> getMetrics() {
         return asList(FILENAME_SIZE, FILENAME_SIZE_RATING);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
The return type is incompatible with Metrics.getMetrics()
```

Would love an explanation how exactly this is solved in the project.

**SOLVED**

Add the following to your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.1</version>
     <configuration>
     <source>${jdk.min.version}</source>
     <target>${jdk.min.version}</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.6</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in your pom.xml ?